Как очистить state у определенного пользователя?
Пытался с помощью этой темы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67096753/aiogram-set-state-for-a-exact-user
Но не получилось даже поставить set_state использовать.
Пытаюсь сделать бота поддержки через супергруппу.
Юзер нажимает на кнопку поддержки, пишет сообщение и это сообщение пересылается и бот присылает кнопку "Принять" (Принять запрос на чат). После чего они общаются и у меня это получилось, но отмену не могу реализовать у обоих. То есть кто то отменяет значит и у другого человека состояние также сбрасывается.
Поэтому прошу разъяснение с темой которую прочитал, ведь у меня не получается поставить даже state с помощью того кода.

Могу предложить хотя бы чуть-чуть углубленно разобраться в том как работают базы данных, потому что использование всяких верхнеуровневых решений на моей практике удобно только для тех кто хоть как-то разбирается в более низкоуровневых концепциях. Попробуйте например sqlite3 использовать, ручками попишите разные SQL query и рано или поздно станете гуру в хранении данных

@dofi4ka, у меня было в планах сделать поддержку через sqlite3, но для меня это костыль. Я увидел способ с внесением в таблицу chatting айди чатов, а потом каждое сообщение от юзера считывать с базы данных этот айдишник проверяв второй айди. Думаю лучше разобраться с машиной состояний чем использовать данный способ с sqlite3
